# SQL Server: Determining games made more than 2 years ago

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question I have is Which developers have games that were released more than two years ago?

My code looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    devName
FROM DEVELOPER as d
    INNER JOIN GAME as g ON d.devID = g.devID
WHERE gameReleaseDate < (WHAT GOES HERE?);
```

I'm unsure how to properly have it find games released more than two years ago, I'm most likely failing to remember something very basic I dont want the answer just how to determine if something is below a certain amount of years.

Comment: in the right side, put DateAdd(Year, -2, Getdate())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should work (assuming that the field being compared is one of the `DATE` / `DATETIME` data types):

```
DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE())
```

[DATEADD on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: Thank you that did in fact work. Could you explain what each thing means? I have never used the DATEADD function.

Comment: is the middle section (-2) always how many years you want it off by? so if I wanted 4 put -4 or if I wanted to see 2019 put 3?

Comment: That's correct, DATEADD() takes three parameters: 1. The date part to add, 2. The amount to add, 3. The date to start from. In this case the amount is negative since we want to go two years into the past. I'll see if I can add a docs link to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Soukai

Comment: I like to... discourage the use of the cryptic datepart parameters (in this example, the `YYYY`) in favor of the descriptive ones (in this case `YEAR`) easier to remember and less error prone (I can't tell you how many times I've used `mm` when I meant `mi`).

Comment: Good call @BenThul... force of habit I guess. I completely agree, and have updated the answer per your suggestion.